# Where is Java Installed on Mac OS X?

Tags: java, macos

I downloaded Java 7u17 on Mac OS 10.7.5 from [here](http://www.java.com/en/download/mac_download.jsp?locale=en) and successfully installed it. To do some JNI programming, I need to know where Java is installed on my Mac.

I thought that inside the `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/` folder, there would be a folder called `1.7.0.jdk` or something, but then I found the folder empty. This was confirmed by running `ls /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/` in the Terminal. I've tried searching for it to find out if it was installed somewhere, but that doesn't seem to be turning anything up.

Could someone please tell me where Java is installed on my Mac?

Comment: To close voters/reopeners - this question is [explicitly not off-topic (questions about tools commonly used by programmers)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Unfortunately, it got bandwagoned by [meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/322704/beyond-confused-about-question-and-answer-reception).

Comment: I found the JDK in **/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/**. I'm using macOS Big Sur(11.0.1). And installed jdk version is 1.8.0

Answer (score 1645, accepted):

Use `/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8` command on a terminal shell to figure out where is your **Java 1.8** home directory

If you just want to find out the home directory of your most recent version of Java, omit the version. e.g. `/usr/libexec/java_home`

Comment: I got to this question because I was getting an error in eclipse on my mac because I was getting an error on the first line of the program "import java.util.*." I strongly suspect this is because the java path isn't set correctly or something (even though I set this up once before). I entered the command in this answer and I get a directory. Can I just paste that directory into the textbox in the "Native library folder config" window? Or does this directory belong somewhere else?

Comment: Added `export JAVA_HOME=\`/usr/libexec/java_home\`` to .bash_profile so JAVA_HOME is always set (note the back-ticks around the libexec command)

Comment: If you just want to know if the JDK is installed on your mac, omit the version number and run from terminal: $ echo $(/usr/libexec/java_home)

Comment: On Mac 10.12.3, we should `/usr/libexec/java_home -- v` to show the most recent version of java

Comment: Note that macOS Big Sur changed the behaviour of the java_home command.  Noe, if if the JAVA_HOME environment variable is already set to a valid JDK that is all it will return, it will ignore the -v parameter.  If JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid folder, the java_home command won't work at all.  To get a reasonable output you must unset JAVA_HOME before invoking `/usr/libexec/java_home`

Comment: I get `The operation couldn’t be completed. Unable to locate a Java Runtime.` - I installed java with brew

Answer (score 190):

You could use

```
/usr/libexec/java_home
```

command in your terminal to know the path where Java being installed.

Comment: I like this solution better than the accepted answer because it is independent of the version of the JVM installed.

Comment: This didn't find my java 8 version installed by Oracle.

Comment: Why do you have the `echo $(...)` there? Doesn't just `/usr/libexec/java_home` do the same?

Comment: The accepted answer did not work for me but this worked! (I'm normally not a mac/unix user)

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann It doesn't work for me without dolar sign and brackets.

Comment: export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home) at ~/.bash_profile

Comment: It is an ancient answer. Go ahead with `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/`

Answer (score 87):

Turns out that I actually had the Java 7 JRE installed, not the JDK. The correct download link is [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html). After installing it, `jdk1.7.0jdk` appears in the JavaVirtualMachines directory.

Comment: For me, it was under `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_60.jdk` (knowing that for the JDK 1.6 the path is : `/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/`)

Comment: export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home) at ~/.bash_profile

Answer (score 47):

If you install just the JRE, it seems to be put at:

```
/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home
```

Comment: You should not rely on this existing. If you need the JRE, bundle inside your own application.

Comment: Setting JAVA_HOME with a path containing a space character is challenging ! I didn't succeeded...

Comment: you can create somewhere a link to this directory and set JAVA_HOME to that link

Comment: This is where the "Java" System Preferences panel seems to install it.

Comment: @AntoineRosset, you can set it this way:
`export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home`

Comment: Thanks. I knew where my JDKs were, I didn't know where the Java plugin installed its JRE.

Comment: export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home) at ~/.bash_profile

Answer (score 39):

Try This, It's easy way to find java installed path in Mac OS X,

GoTO

1 ) **/Library i.e Macintosh HD/Library**

[image]

2) **Click on Library in that we find Java folder.**

[image]

3) **So final path is**

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_144.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Hope so this is help for someone .

Comment: Pretty helpful when you have to point the JDK explicitly from an IDE. Thanks

Comment: How Dense am I?  My terminal says that I have 2 jdk's installed in /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/ but I can't find them when I navigate to that directory in finder... How dense can I get...

Comment: @SoftwareSavant, Please ref  https://stackoverflow.com/a/14875241 answer ,It's may be help you .

Answer (score 38):

Use unix find function to find javas installed...

```
sudo find / -name java
```

Comment: You do not need sudo to run find for generally-accessible commands. If you don't want to see the error messages about inaccessible directories, get rid of the messages rather than using root privs unnecessarily. Using sudo all the time is a bad habit. Redirect stderr to /dev/null, like this:

find / -name java 2> /dev/null

Comment: What should i do if i need too look under inaccessible directories ?

Comment: Walter's point is that the `java` binary will be world readable, therefore `sudo` is not necessary.  Your answer is still useful :)

Comment: Yes, I just used this to find src.zip (the source code of the java jdk)

Comment: export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home) at ~/.bash_profile

Comment: use "sudo find / -name java 2>/dev/null" to filter out junk err messages. 2 is error. It will get redirected to /dev/null which does nothing.

Answer (score 25):

If you type

```
java -verbose
```

This also gives the location from which the jars are loaded and hence also the java path.

Comment: I added export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home) at ~/.bash_profile.

Answer (score 23):

Java package structure of Mac OS is a bit different from Windows. Don't be upset for this as a developer just needs to set `PATH` and `JAVA_HOME`.

So in `.bash_profile` set `JAVA_HOME` and `PATH` as below. This example is for Java 6:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
export PATH=/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: This removes about everything else from the path? Do this only if you are only using Java and nothing else in your system.

Comment: export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home) at ~/.bash_profile.

Answer (score 22):

You may not realize it, but you likely have multiple Java versions installed.

To list the version, architecture, and folder location of **all** installed JVMs on your Mac:

`$ /usr/libexec/java_home --verbose`

Or:

`$ /usr/libexec/java_home -V` (That's an uppercase V!)

Sample output:

```
$ /usr/libexec/java_home -V
Matching Java Virtual Machines (4):
    12.0.1 (x86_64) "Oracle Corporation" - "Java SE 12.0.1" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-12.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home
    1.8.202.08 (x86_64) "Oracle Corporation" - "Java" /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home
    1.8.0_282 (x86_64) "Amazon" - "Amazon Corretto 8" /Users/username/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/corretto-1.8.0_282/Contents/Home
    1.8.0_202 (x86_64) "Oracle Corporation" - "Java SE 8" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_202.jdk/Contents/Home
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-12.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Comment: This is a more complete answer IMHO. I had multiple versions installed and the /Internet Plug-Ins/... was causing an issue with the Java updater tool, but I couldn't find the version the tool was complaining about ... until now.

Answer (score 12):

just write `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/`
in Go to Folder --> Go in Finder

Comment: ok, I just tried this and I managed to navigate to the directory.  Why can't I navigate to that folder normally in Finder?  Is this just Apple being extra annoying... Also extra annoying, Gradle version 4.3 doesn't work with any version of Java except for Java 8

Comment: export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home) at ~/.bash_profile

Comment: this folder is empty in my case ... but when i check java -version ... it show version 1.8

Answer (score 12):

type `which java` in terminal to show where it is installed.

Comment: Yes, export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home) at ~/.bash_profile.

Answer (score 10):

Edited: Alias to current java version is `/Library/Java/Home`

For more information: [a link](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1170/_index.html)

Comment: That would be an alias for the most recent version, which would correctly point to Java 7 SDK once it is installed.

Comment: This link only exists for legacy purposes, and will not be updated by installing Java 7. Do not use this path.

Comment: I updated export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home) at ~/.bash_profile.

Answer (score 8):

For :

- OS X : 10.11.6
- Java : 8

I confirm the answer of @Morrie .

```
   export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home;
```

But if you are running containers your life will be easier

Comment: I think this should have been a comment.

Comment: I dont think , because there is an Added value which is ` export JAVA_HOME=`. ... What about you @Thunderforge

Comment: export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home) at ~/.bash_profile.

Answer (score 7):

I have just installed the JDK for version 21 of Java SE 7 and found that it is installed in a different directory from Apple's Java 6. It is in /Library/Java... rather then in /System/Library/Java.... Running /usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.7 versus -v 1.6 will confirm this.

Comment: export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home) at ~/.bash_profile

Answer (score 7):

I tried serkan's solution, it found java 7's location on OS X Mavericks.
it is resided in `"/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_51.jdk/"`
but to make it the default JDK I had to set JAVA_HOME system variable in .bash_profile in home directory to `"/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home/"`
so its up and running now thanks to serkan's idea

Comment: export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home) at ~/.bash_profile.

Answer (score 4):

Try to check in here
`/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines`

Answer (score 2):

if you are using [sdkman](https://sdkman.io/usage)

you can check it with `sdk home java <installed_java_version>`

```
$  sdk home java 8.0.252.j9-adpt
/Users/admin/.sdkman/candidates/java/8.0.252.j9-adpt
```

you can get your installed java version with

```
$ sdk list java
```

Answer (score 0):

The System Preferences then Java control panel then Java then View will show the exact location of the currently installed default JRE.

Comment: export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home) at ~/.bash_profile

Answer (score 0):

MacOS BigSur

Add following under .zshrc file. If .zshrc is not present, create and add.

```
export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home`
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply enter the following in your terminal :

```
whereis java
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's installed via IntelliJ IDEA. It's at ~/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines