# Eclipse IDE errors in every line of code

Tags: java, eclipse

I am learning to code in java, and using Eclipse, the android IDE as my code writing program. Whenever I create a new project, there is always a red exclamation mark on the icon for the main folder of my project in the project explorer section on the left side of the screen. Also, whenever I create a new class file, some of the code has an error in it, even when it shouldn't. One example of this is when I add the main method, with this code: `public static void main(String[] args)` I get the error "String cannot be resolved to a type".

There is also an automatically generated line of code at the beginning of the class which has an error in it: `public class Class` is giving me the error: "Implicit super constructor Object() is undefined for default constructor. Must define an explicit constructor" there is a red dotted line under the word "Class" in the code, so I assume its trying to tell me that's where the error is.

I am also getting an error in the code `System.out.println();`saying "System cannot be resolved".

I was able to create an integer without getting an error using this code: `int number = 3;`

I was able to use all this code mentioned above without getting an error before, I don't know what's wrong... Could I have changed some settings or something?

screenshot of eclipse [image: errors in eclipse]

Comment: Looks like you're not pointing to a JDK/SDK for your project.

Comment: Also, don't call your class `Class`, lest you interfere with `java.lang.Class`.

Comment: Don't name your class `Class`

Comment: Are you actually creating an Android app?  Setting those up is different.

Comment: @DaveNewton how do i fix this?

Comment: @ajb at the moment i'm not creating an android app, im still learning java

Comment: The first thing you need to do is rename your class name like others have said above.

Comment: I changed the class to a different name, now what?

Comment: Now try to run the code. Is it still giving an error? If so tell us what the error is.

Comment: I renamed my class to Bob, ran the code, and got this error: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Bob
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Bob
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
 at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)`

Comment: Right click on your project > properties > java build path > libraries. Do you see JRE System Library?

Comment: Did you also change the name of the source file `Class.java` to `Bob.java`?

Comment: Also you need to change the name of the java file to Bob

Comment: @Noob I see "JRE System Library [javaSE-1.7] (unbound)"

Comment: Go to Window > preferences > java > installed JREs. Is JRE there?

Comment: @ajb i deleted `Class.java` and created a new one named `Bob.java` which contains the exact same code that `Class.java` had, except for the `int number = 3;` and the `System.out.println();`

Comment: @Noob the only thing i see there is `Java SE 6 (MacOS X Default) (default)`

Comment: Find where thats located, then change the java build path to wherever java 6 is.

Comment: @Noob how do I do that? I see the location of it, but how do I change the build path?

Comment: First basic question: did you install Java Development Kit (JDK)?

Comment: @Pshemo i downloaded the SDK ADT bundle for mac from the android developer website. Whatever came with that, i have. I dont think it comes with the JDK, but I could be wrong

Comment: I wouldn't trust the Android bundle to work for non-Android-app projects, but I'm sure others know more about this than I do.

Comment: To be sure download [official JDK](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index-jsp-138363.html) and install it. Later let eclipse know about its installed location. Go to `Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Installed JREs` and `add` `SrandardVM` and as directory set up folder with installed JDK.

Comment: @ajb it was working perfectly fine before, then suddenly i think i did something and it stopped working

Comment: @Pshemo its asking me for the JRE home directory, and i don't know what folder it is...

Comment: If you installed Java then based on [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15826202/where-is-java-7-installed-on-mac-os-x) question it seems that its directory should be in `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/`. In case of JRE you can also check something like `/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.6`. If not there check directory where you installed `SDK ADT`.

Comment: @Pshemo when i put /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0.jdk/Contents/Home in the jre home section, a bunch of stuff came up in the jre system libraries section. what do i do next? do i have to put anything in the "Default VM arguments" section?

Comment: I am not sure if JDK 8 (the newes is) the best choice for you since it may be not yet supported by Android (I am not sure but wouldn't be surprised). I would try with JDK 7. Also `a bunch of stuff came up in the jre system libraries section` That is OK. `what do i do next? do i have to put anything in the "Default VM arguments" section?` You don't have do add any VM arguments. If you want to enable assertions you can use `-ea` but that is not mandatory. If you can then just click finish and make your project use this version of JDK.

Comment: @Pshemo okay, I created a new java project in eclipse using JDK 8, and it seems to be working now, if i encounter any problems with android compatibility, i will try JDK 7. THANK YOU SO MUCH! I honestly had no idea what was wrong, i really appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

Make a new project with any other name than a [Reserved keyword](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/_keywords.html).

You get errors because you changed your class name, when your compiler looks for the old name. Try clean and build.

Edit:give your package a name, and write

```
package yourname;
```

at the start of your .java file, before ANY code.

Comment: I was having this same problem in other projects i created where i used names that were not reserved keywords

Comment: Try renaming your package and writing `package yourname` at the start of the .java file. If that doesn't work neither, I got no other ideas.

Comment: @user3308082 The JRE System Library node you've shown does not appear to be expandable. Could it be that you've removed or upgraded your Java version and the `Installed JREs` preference page's contents are stale--meaning you really *don't* have the standard classes that Eclipse says are not found, at least not where it thinks they are?