# Java Developer Kit executable unable to be found

Tags: java, mysql, environment-variables

I'm trying to install mysql on my Mac using the command

```
sudo apt install mysql
```

and it said I needed to install JDK on it. So I installed JDK but am receiving an error saying:

> Unable to locate an executable at "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-9.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/apt" (-1)

I have updated my env path to

```
JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/Home
```

But when I install JDK theres no java file anywhere in my library, even though when I check to see if I have installed it, it is successfully found. I've installed Homebrew but do not know what package to install after the initial installation, or if this is the problem.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15826202/where-is-java-installed-on-mac-os-x

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where is Java Installed on Mac OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15826202/where-is-java-installed-on-mac-os-x)

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Yes when I echo the directory supposedly is found but when I try to go to cd to it, it cannot find it, and the executable still cannot be found.

Comment: Apt used to be a tool (Annotation Processing Tool) included with Java, but it was removed in Java 8. However I fail to see how it would be used to install mysql. I think you are mixing up commands, and maybe meant `apt-get` instead (which afaik doesn't work on a Mac).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Mac it would be much easier to install Homebrew from https://brew.sh and then use $ brew install mysql

see this [link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/80721) for the apt and yum command usage