# AS3 - Get JAVA Home path

Tags: java, actionscript-3, apache-flex

I need to copy an extension on Java Home lib directory.
But my problem is to find java home on Windows and on Mac OS.
This directory change on each idk update.
Could you help to fix it with environnement variables.
Best regards.

Comment: What's an IDK update? Are you looking for path of **JDK** (for compiling Java apps) or **JRE** (for running Java apps)? By not showing **what you've tried** it means **the answer is longer** since I have no idea how much info you need to know... Anyway hope it's useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

> Could you help to fix it with `Environment Variables`?

Can you be sure that your app user has **actually** added `JAVA_HOME` path into their account's Environment settings? If they didn't follow some tutorial then your idea will find nothing.

> But my problem is to find `JAVA_HOME` on Windows and on Mac OS.

You can use terminal commands to find `JAVA_HOME`.

**Mac OS**: ([**source**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15826712) : untested since no Mac available)

```
/usr/libexec/java_home
```

**Windows OS**: (using `cmd.exe` command line)

***Option 1*** : Normally `set` adds new entry **into** Environment Variables, but if used without parameters it will just list the existing Environment Variables.

```
set
```

which gives me result of long text including :

```
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_102
JDK_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102
JRE_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_102\jre
```

***Option 2*** : (gets system's current `Java.exe` path)

```
for %i in (java.exe) do @echo.   %~$PATH:i
```

which gives me one result of : `C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_102\bin\java.exe`

***Option 3*** : For Windows I think the best option is to check Windows **registry** for user's `currentVersion` and then check the `JavaHome` of that specific  currentVersion.

(a) Check for Java **current version** used by Windows...

```
REG QUERY HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\ /v "CurrentVersion" /s
```

***note*** : Or just do `java -version` to get the correct number for next step (b).

(b) Check for Java **Home path** based on the above found version (eg: **1.8** 
 or **1.8.0_102**)...

```
REG QUERY HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\ /v "JavaHome" /s
```

Practice the above options in the `cmd.exe` window to see their output easily.

Later, in your AS3 code, you can use `Regular Expression` or `String` functions extract the number or directory path that you need.

***Options ++*** : Other options include using `where /r c:\ java.exe` to search `c:\` drive for the file location (folder) but can be slow on large drives (is aphabetical and searches **all** sub-folders).

---

You asked about Environment Variables (not Registry) so below is a quick example to do that ***Option 1*** for Windows.

(PS: if you get an error about *"Native Process is not supported"* when testing in IDE you tick **only** "Extended Desktop" in your AIR settings, then later for exported runtime version you must un-tick that and now tick only "Desktop").

Example testable code for Windows which silently opens CMD.exe and passes `set` command, then receives its returned text output. The code can be shortened by you...

```
package {

import flash.display.MovieClip;

import flash.events.*;
import flash.errors.*;

import flash.desktop.NativeProcess;
import flash.desktop.*;

import flash.filesystem.File;

import flash.utils.ByteArray;


public class Java_Get_Path_v3 extends MovieClip 
{

    private var NProcessExe:File;

    private var NProcess :NativeProcess; //external Process (eg: notepad.exe)
    private var nativeProcessStartupInfo :NativeProcessStartupInfo;
    private var NProcess_Args :Vector.<String> = new Vector.<String>(); //Process startup options

    private var str_CMD_Output :String = "";

    private var str_Java_Home :String = "";
    private var str_JDK_Home :String = "";
    private var str_JRE_Home :String = "";

    private var temp_Int :int = -1;


    public function Java_Get_Path_v3() 
    {
        //# 1) setup Native Process (Command Line runs in background (no window) )
        createNativeProcess();

        //# 2) get Java "Home" path from Windows via "Environment Variables";
        get_Java_Path(); //is via stdout

    }


    private function createNativeProcess():void 
    {
        if (NativeProcess.isSupported) 
        {
            trace("## doing FUNCTION : createNativeProcess()" );

            var pathToEXE:String = "c:/windows/system32/cmd.exe";
            NProcessExe = File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath(pathToEXE);

            if (NProcessExe.exists)
            {
                //# initialise Process
                NProcess = new NativeProcess();

                //# add Process listeners for events
                NProcess.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, STD_onOutputData); 
                NProcess.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.STANDARD_OUTPUT_DATA, STD_onOutputData); 
                NProcess.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.STANDARD_ERROR_DATA, STD_onErrorData); 

                NProcess.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.STANDARD_OUTPUT_IO_ERROR, STD_onIOError);
                NProcess.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.STANDARD_ERROR_IO_ERROR, STD_onIOError);
            } 
            else 
            { trace("The specified .exe file was not found"); }

        } 
        else //# if  NOT suppoNativeProcess.
        {
            trace("Native Process not supported in this mode (use only \"Extended Desktop\" when debugging)");
        }
    }


    private function get_Java_Path():void 
    {
        //# use to get Java Home path
        NProcess_Args[0] = ("\/c" + "set");

        //# use to get Java version
        //NProcess_Args[0] = ("\/c" + "java -version");

        //# start the Native Process (eg: silent running of CMD.exe)
        //# triggers :::: public function STD_onOutputData
        nativeProcessStartupInfo = new NativeProcessStartupInfo();
        nativeProcessStartupInfo.executable = NProcessExe;
        nativeProcessStartupInfo.arguments = NProcess_Args;

        NProcess.start(nativeProcessStartupInfo);

    }


    private function update_String_with_Path():void 
    {
        trace("## doing FUNCTION : update_String_with_Path()" );

        //trace("str_CMD_Output : " + str_CMD_Output);

        temp_Int = str_CMD_Output.indexOf("JAVA_HOME"); //trace("temp_Int :" + temp_Int);
        str_Java_Home = str_CMD_Output.substring( temp_Int, (str_CMD_Output.indexOf("\n", temp_Int ) ) );

        temp_Int = str_CMD_Output.indexOf("JDK_HOME"); //trace("temp_Int :" + temp_Int);
        str_JDK_Home = str_CMD_Output.substring( temp_Int, (str_CMD_Output.indexOf("\n", temp_Int ) ) );

        temp_Int = str_CMD_Output.indexOf("JRE_HOME"); //trace("temp_Int :" + temp_Int)
        str_JRE_Home = str_CMD_Output.substring( temp_Int, (str_CMD_Output.indexOf("\n", temp_Int ) ) );

        trace("==================================");

        trace("str_Java_Home : " + str_Java_Home);
        trace("str_JDK_Home  : " + str_JDK_Home);
        trace("str_JRE_Home  : " + str_JRE_Home);

    }


    public function STD_onOutputData(event:ProgressEvent):void 
    { 
        trace("## doing FUNCTION : STD_onOutputData( ... )" );

        if (NProcess && NProcess.running)
        {
            if (NProcess.standardOutput.bytesAvailable > 0)
            {
                trace("got bytes in... STD OUT : ");

                //# Receive CMD.exe output (UTF bytes) into String...
                str_CMD_Output = NProcess.standardOutput.readUTFBytes(NProcess.standardOutput.bytesAvailable);

                trace("str_CMD_Output.length : " + str_CMD_Output.length + " characters");

                trace("## end of... STD_Out ::: ");

                update_String_with_Path();

            }

        }
    }


    public function STD_onErrorData(event:ProgressEvent):void 
    {
        trace("## doing FUNCTION : STD_onErrorData( ... )" );

        if (NProcess.running == true)
        {
            //# sometimes Native Process output is in std-Error instead of std-Output
            //# (is decided by the running .EXE file)

            trace("## end of... STD_Error ::: ");
        }
    }


    public function STD_onIOError(event:IOErrorEvent):void 
    { trace(event.toString()); }


    private function STD_errorHandler(e:AsyncErrorEvent):void 
    { trace('ERROR: ' + e.text); }


} //end Class

} //end Package
```