# Opening an SWF file in a new window

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, flash-cs6

I have a button in my desktop flash application, when clicked, it must load an external SWF file and open it in a new window without using the browser.
i've tried

```
import flash.system.fscommand;

loadButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickHandler);
function clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void {
      fscommand ("exec", "external.swf");
 }
```

But it didn't work. Someone mentioned in a forum that the app must be compiled as   a .EXE file for this code to work. is that true?.

i've also tried

```
loadButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickHandler);
function clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void {
      navigateToURL(new URLRequest("external.swf"), "_blank");
 }
```

But this opens the file in a new browser window.
Any idea how can i do it without using the browser window?

Comment: https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/NativeWindow.html

Comment: So this is an AIR application for desktop? It needs to be. Use the `NativeProcess` feature to load `cmd.exe` with parameters `start C:\someFolder\external.swf`.. Try [**this code here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47700996/as3-get-java-home-path/47745703#47745703) as a quick test. Just replace `NProcess_Args[0] = ("\/c" + "set");` with this command `NProcess_Args[0] = ("\/c" + "start C:\someFolder\external.swf");`

Comment: @VC.One I don't think it's appropriate as you have no idea what kind of application is associated with SWF file there (could be none at all, or browser, or media player) and you don't even know if Standalone Flash Projector is installed. I believe that opening another AIR window and loading the external SWF via **Loader** will be the best solution.

Comment: @Organis if asker does not have standalone player then how do they even know it's possible to _"open it in a new window without using the browser"_? (ie: they have seen the Standalone window before, they simply cannot confuse it with VLC or some browser window). Also the installed `FlashPlayerDebugger.exe` achieves same thing as the Standalone version... PS: Either way sounds good and should be tested by asker for learning experience and options weighting.

Comment: Thank you both for your help, @Organis i used the NativeWindow class and successfuly opened a new window but how can i load an SWF file inside that window? because i don't have access to it.

Comment: @user3010564 Added an answer. It is pretty much self-explanatory.

Comment: @user3010564 If the provided answer is working then accept as correct Answer by ticking the `✔` icon. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is simple with the **NativeWindow**. Despite the fact the **NativeWindow** is a separate window, your application is still a whole and have a full access to everything, the new window included. You just need to add a **Loader** with another SWF to the new window's stage.

```
// This is an example from official docs:
// https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/NativeWindow.html#NativeWindow()
var windowOptions:NativeWindowInitOptions = new NativeWindowInitOptions();
windowOptions.systemChrome = NativeWindowSystemChrome.STANDARD;
windowOptions.type = NativeWindowType.NORMAL;

var newWindow:NativeWindow = new NativeWindow(windowOptions);
newWindow.stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
newWindow.stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
newWindow.bounds = new Rectangle(100, 100, 800, 800);

newWindow.activate();

// Now the only thing left is to load the external SWF into it:
var aLoader:Loader = new Loader;

// Load SWF as usual:
aLoader.load(new URLRequest("external.swf"));

// Add it as a child to the new window's stage:
newWindow.stage.addChild(aLoader);
```

Comment: Thanks, it helped a lot. One more thing, when i load the SWF file in the new window, it doesn't use the full space available, image:[link](https://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/524470zer.png) the SWF file content appears on top left i tried using: stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN; but no results any ideas?

Comment: @user3010564 Did you try set the new window bounds to actual SWF width and height?

Comment: Yes, the SWF file i want to load in the new window has a size of 1280x800. This the what i did: newWindow.bounds = new Rectangle(100, 100, 1280, 800);. when the new window opens, it has a size of 1280x800 and SWF file fits perfectly, but when i maximize the window i get the result that i shared in the image above.

Comment: @user3010564 Play with **scaleMode** of the window's **stage**. Probaly you need to set it to **StageScaleMode.SHOW_ALL**.