# JavaVM FATAL: Failed to load the jvm library

Tags: java, c++, jvm

I am trying to start the jvm using c++ . Here is My CmakeLists.txt and ny C++ code.

My System is macOS Mojave 10.14.6

Java using homebrew cask install

openjdk version "1.8.0_232"

OpenJDK Runtime Environment (AdoptOpenJDK)(build 1.8.0_232-b09)

OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (AdoptOpenJDK)(build 25.232-b09, mixed mode)

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
project(jvm)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

include_directories(
        /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/include
        /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/include/darwin
)

link_libraries(
        /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/JavaVM
)

add_executable(jvm main.cpp)
```

```
#include <iostream>
#include "jni.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
    JavaVM *jvm;
    JNIEnv *env;

    JavaVMOption jvmopt[3];
    jvmopt[0].optionString = "-Djava.compiler=NONE";
    jvmopt[1].optionString = "-Djava.class.path=./"; 

    jvmopt[2].optionString=  "-verbose:class";

    JavaVMInitArgs vmArgs;
    vmArgs.version = JNI_VERSION_1_8;
    vmArgs.nOptions = 1;
    vmArgs.options = jvmopt;
    vmArgs.ignoreUnrecognized = JNI_TRUE;

    long  flag = JNI_CreateJavaVM(&jvm, (void **) &env, &vmArgs);
    cout << flag << endl;

    jvm->DestroyJavaVM();
    return 0;
}
```

The result of the main function run

```
JavaVM: Failed to load JVM: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/bundle/Libraries/libserver.dylib
JavaVM FATAL: Failed to load the jvm library.
```

[UPDATE]

PROBLEM SLOVED !!!

The reason is I link the wrong library.

I should link $JAVA_HOME//lib/server/libjvm.dylib

What's more , I use oracle JDK instead of openjdk. Maybe something wrong with openjdk!!

Comment: `vmArgs.nOptions = 1;` -- Shouldn't this be `vmArgs.nOptions = 3;`?

Comment: I try but still the same @PaulMcKenzie

Comment: Well, I know that in Windows, the jvm (in the case of Windows, `jvm.dll`) and related libraries must be on the path.  Your error seems to suggest that the system cannot find these libraries.

Comment: Do you know which file is the same as jvm.dll in windows?

Comment: [Does this help?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15826202/where-is-java-installed-on-mac-os-x)

Comment: problem sloved. I link the wrong library. I should link $JAVA_HOME//lib/server/libjvm.dylib , What's more , I use oracle JDK instead of  openjdk

Comment: @stevenchan could you please update your original question, maybe add an `updated` section near the bottom where you explain how you fixed it?  That way, other people can benefit from this in the future.

Answer (score 30):

Steps to resolve the issue (JavaVM: Failed to load JVM:.../libserver.dylib):

```
cd /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_271.jdk/Contents/Home
cd lib
```

Create a softlink libjvm.dylib as libserver.dylib:

```
sudo ln -s ../jre/lib/server/libjvm.dylib libserver.dylib
```

Comment: When trying to start Apache Directory Studio, I was getting `JavaVM: Failed to load JVM: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_271.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/libserver.dylib
JavaVM FATAL: Failed to load the jvm library.`. This solution resolved it for me.

Answer (score 4):

```
sudo ln -s /Library/Java//JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_74.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/server/libjvm.dylib /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_74.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/libserver.dylib
```

alternatively that worked for me