# How do I find the path to the JDK downloaded on my mac?

Tags: java, javac

```
javac -version
```

This command gives the correct updated version, so I think the JDK was installed correctly. I need to know its location. How can I find the path to the JDK?

Comment: Probably a duplicate of [*Where is Java Installed on Mac OS X?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15826202/642706).

Comment: Related: [*How to install Java 8 on Mac*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24342886/642706)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines
```

Comment: Bingo, this is the standard location for [JVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine)s on [macOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS) in the last several years.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following command on a terminal:

```
/usr/libexec/java_home
```

To find the location of your jdk install.

Hope this helps!